# Downloading files from the Internet using Powershell with progress

Tags: http, powershell, response, progress, tinyurl

I have been working on a powershell script that uses a .txt file to download multiple files from tinyurls. I have been successful in using `Jobs` to make this happen simultaneously, thanks to those on this forum. 
The project requires some pretty large files to be downloaded, and using the current method has no progress indicator.  I figured some users might think the program died. Looking for a way give a status of where it is in the download.  Here is what I came up with, but I'm lost in how to pipe this information back out to the console. Any suggestions?

```
#Checks to see if NT-Download folder is on the Desktop, if not found, creates it
$DOCDIR = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$TARGETDIR = "$DOCDIR\NT-Download"
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
}

$filepaths = Resolve-Path "files.txt"

Get-Content "$filepaths" | Foreach {
Start-Job {
    function Save-TinyUrlFile
    {
        PARAM (
            $TinyUrl,
            $DestinationFolder
        )

        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $TinyUrl
        $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($response.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.OriginalString)
        $filepath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($DestinationFolder, $filename)
        $totalLength = [System.Math]::Floor($response.get_ContentLength()/1024) 
        $responseStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
        $buffer = new-object byte[] 10KB
        $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length) 
        $downloadedBytes = $count
        try
        {
            $filestream = [System.IO.File]::Create($filepath)
            $response.RawContentStream.WriteTo($filestream)
            $filestream.Close()
            while ($count -gt 0) 
            { 
                [System.Console]::CursorLeft = 0 
                [System.Console]::Write("Downloaded {0}K of {1}K", [System.Math]::Floor($downloadedBytes/1024), $totalLength) 
                $targetStream.Write($buffer, 0, $count) 
                $count = $responseStream.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.length) 
                $downloadedBytes = $downloadedBytes + $count 
            } 
                         "`nFinished Download" 
            $targetStream.Flush()
            $targetStream.Close() 
            $targetStream.Dispose() 
            $responseStream.Dispose() 
        }
        finally
        {
            if ($filestream)
            {
                $filestream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    Save-TinyUrlFile -TinyUrl $args[0] -DestinationFolder $args[1]
} -ArgumentList $_, "$TARGETDIR"
```

}

Comment: Try the bits cmdlets which have a built-in progress indicator.  https://msmvps.com/blogs/it-is-etc/archive/2011/04/25/bits-transfer-powershell-cmdlets.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Write-Progress](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849902.aspx)

> PS C:> for ($i = 1; $i -le 100; $i++ )
>   {write-progress -activity "Search in Progress" -status "$i% Complete:" -percentcomplete $i;}

Answer (score 0):

Far more simple way : rely on Bits:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $tinyUrl
```